# X is a predictable proccess iff X is $\{ F_{t^-}\}$-adapted?

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis

I have read in a remark that:

A stochastic process X is a predictable process iff X is $\{F_{t^-}\}$-adapted. $\quad$ (*)

1. Does the filtration need to satisfy any requirements for (*) to be true?
2. Can someone prove (*) or tell me a book where I can I find a proof?

Comment: For a Poisson process$\{X_t\}$ and its natural filtration $\{\mathscr{F}_t\}$(satisfying usual conditions), $X_t$ is not predictable, but $X_t$ is $\mathscr{F}_{t-}$ measuable.

Comment: @JGWang A poisson process is $\{ \mathscr{F}_t \}$-adapted but not $\{ \mathscr{F}_{t^-} \}$-adapted, which is what I'm saying in my question.

Comment: @UBM: Your question 1. is relevant here. If the filtrations are completed in the usual way, then the filtration of a Poisson process satisfies $\mathcal F_{t-}=\mathcal F_t$ for all $t>0$.

Comment: @JohnDawkins: What do you mean by completed in the usual way? I would say that $ \mathscr{F}_{t^-} = \mathscr{F}_{t} $ if the filtration is left-continuous, right?

Comment: @UBM For a Poisson process $X_t$, $P(X_{t-}=X_t)=1, \forall t>0$, so $X_t\in\mathscr{F}_{t-}$.

Comment: @JGWang: I don't get it, a Poisson process is right-continuous, not left-continuous.

Comment: @UBM: First complete the $\sigma$-field $\mathcal F$ with respect to $\Bbb P$; let $\mathcal N$ denote $\Bbb P$-null sets in that completion. Now augment $\mathcal F_t$ (the $\sigma$-field generated by the Poisson process up to time $t$) with $\mathcal N$, forming $\mathcal G_t := \sigma\{\mathcal F_t,\mathcal N\}$. One has $\mathcal G_{t-}=\mathcal G_t=\mathcal G_{t+}$ for all $t$, essentially because the probability that a Poisson process jumps at any one fixed time $t$ is zero.

Comment: @UBM Please distinguish the difference between "$P(X_{t-}=X_t)=1, \forall t>0$" and "$X$ is continuous in path". Meanwhile, thanks to John Dawkins, in above he also gives a very nice answer.

Comment: @JohnDawkins: Thank you. So the filtration $\{ \mathscr{G}_t \}$ from your example would satisfy the usual conditions (that JGWang was saying in his first message), right? However, I don't understand this part of your message: "One has $\mathscr{G}_{t^-}=\mathscr{G}_{t}=\mathscr{G}_{t^+}$ for all , essentially because the probability that a Poisson process jumps at any one fixed time  is zero". You are saying that the filtration $\{ \mathscr{G}_t  \}$ is both, right-continuous and left-continuous, right? I understand why it is right-continuous. But, why is also left continuous?

Comment: Because the only thing new that ever happens is that the Poisson process jumps, and the chance of a jump at a fixed $t$ is $0$. Details in my second answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More precisely, the $\sigma$-field $\mathcal F_t$ is generated by events of the form 
$$
A=\left[\cap_{k=1}^n\{X_{s_k}\in I_k\}\right]\cap\{X_t\in I\},
$$
where $0\le s_1<s_1<\cdots<s_n<t$, and $I$ and each $I_k$ is an open interval in $\Bbb R$.
If you replace $\{X_t\in I\}$ in this display with $\{X_{t-}\in I\}$, you get a new event (let's call it $B$) that lies in $\mathcal F_{t-}$ and is such that 
$$
\Bbb P[A\Delta B]\le\Bbb P[X_t\not=X_{t-}]=0.
$$
That is, each of the generators of $\mathcal F_t$ is an element of $\mathcal G_{t-}$. It follows that $\mathcal F_t\subset\mathcal G_{t-}$, whence $\mathcal G_t\subset\mathcal G_{t-}$.

Answer (score 2):

(If you read ($*$) in a book, it is probably best to throw that book out the window or start using it as a doorstop.)

The "prototype" predictable process (in the context of some filtered probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal F,(\mathcal F_t)_{t\ge 0},\Bbb P)$) is a process that is left-continuous and adapted to $(\mathcal F_t)$. The $\sigma$-algebra on $[0,\infty)\times\Omega$ generated by such processes, call it $\mathcal P$, is the predictable $\sigma$-algebra. Finally, a process $X: (\omega,t)\to X_t(\omega)$ is predictable provided  it is $\mathcal P$ measurable. A convenient place to read about such things is the blog Almost Sure of Geo. Lowther: https://almostsure.wordpress.com/.

Comment: I said $\{F_{t^-}\}$-adapted, not $\{F_t\}$-adapted. Thanks for the website but it is too hard for me. Do you have an answer to my questions?

Comment: Question 1 mainly.

Comment: The correct characterization of predictable is as I've stated—the remark you read is incorrect. The answer to your first question is "NO".

Comment: Ok, thank you. It's clear now.